# AngularCli - Subscribe is not being executed inside onSubmit during test

Tags: angular, angular-cli, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to test a component that basically have a field for email and password. Once these two fields are filled, than the user can click in the button and send a request to the server. When I test this component through browser it executes the behavior that I want. But when I use the spec file to test the component the `subscribe` method is never executed (obs: I'm mocking the service). Here is the `onSubmit` method for the component:

```js
onSubmit(formAuthentication: NgForm) {
  if (this.credential.email == undefined || this.credential.password == undefined) {
    this.error = "Preencha o campo de email e de senha para continuar"
    return;
  } else {
    this.tokenManagerService.generateNewToken(this.credential);
    this.tokenManagerService.retrieveToken().subscribe(token => {
      console.log(token);
      const tokenRetrieved = JSON.parse(token);
      if (tokenRetrieved.error) {
        this.error = tokenRetrieved.error;
      } else {
        foo();
      }
    });
    formAuthentication.resetForm();
  }
}
```

This is the configuration for the spec file and the test itself:

```js
describe('AuthenticationComponent', () => {
  let component: AuthenticationComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AuthenticationComponent>;
  let inputEmail: HTMLInputElement;
  let inputPassword: HTMLInputElement;
  let loginButton: HTMLInputElement;
  let tokenManagerServiceMock: TokenManagerServiceMock;
  let mockRouter = {
    navigate: jasmine.createSpy('navigate')
  }
  beforeEach(() => {
    tokenManagerServiceMock = new TokenManagerServiceMock();
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ AuthenticationComponent ],
      imports: [ FormsModule, HttpModule,RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([]) ],
      providers: [
        { provide: TokenManagerService, useValue: tokenManagerServiceMock }
      ]
    });
    TestBed.overrideComponent(AuthenticationComponent, {
      set: {
        providers: [
          { provide: TokenManagerService, useValue: tokenManagerServiceMock }
        ]
      }
    });

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AuthenticationComponent)
    fixture.componentInstance.ngOnInit();
    tokenManagerServiceMock = TestBed.get(TokenManagerService);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    inputEmail = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('input[type=text]');
    inputPassword = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('input[type=password]');
    loginButton = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('input[type=submit]');
  });

  it('should detect white field message',() => {
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      inputEmail.value = faker.internet.email();
      inputEmail.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
      inputPassword.value = faker.internet.password();
      inputPassword.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
      loginButton.click();
      fixture.detectChanges();
    });
  });
});
```

What I could possibly doing wrong?

**EDIT 1**:  I'm pretty sure that the `subscribe` method is never executed, because inside the subscribe method, if there is a node called `token.error`, the component should set an error variable to be displayed in this block:

```
<div class="error-block" *ngIf="error">
  <h6>{{ error }}</h6>
</div>
```

But this message never appears in the Karma.

**EDIT 2**:
This is my mockService to simulate the original authentication service:

```
import { Injectable }  from '@angular/core';
import { Credential } from '../models/credential';
import { AuthenticationService } from './authentication.service'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import * as token from 'rand-token';

@Injectable()
export class TokenManagerServiceMock {

  private tokenKey: string = 'codeToken';
  private subject = new Subject<any>();

  constructor() {}

  public generateNewToken(credential: Credential): void {
    let currentTime:number = (new Date()).getTime();
    if (credential.email == 'eminetto@coderockr.com') {
      const data = token.suid(24);
      this.subject.next(JSON.stringify({ttl: currentTime, data}));
    } else {
      const error = 'Usuário ou senha inválidos';
      this.subject.next(JSON.stringify({ttl: currentTime, error}));
    }
  }

  public retrieveToken(): Observable<string> {
    console.log('achieved retrieve');
    return this.subject.asObservable();
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide details around what you've debugged to happen in your test `'should detect white field message'` so that others can try to assist. (e.g. how you know it isn't executing the subscribe, etc)

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel there is a `console.log` over there and is never executed

Comment: Again, please provide details stating exactly what you are experiencing and what you've done so far to debug the problem (providing above in your question)

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel updated the topic

Comment: Can you provide details around your `TokenManagerServiceMock` class to show how it is mocking the methods (`generateNewToken(...)`, `retrieveToken(...)`) that are used in the class under test (`AuthenticationComponent`)?

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel  updated again the topic with the mockService

Comment: Try changing the `Subject` to a `BehaviorSubject` in your mock class

Comment: Thanks my friend! It worked! Please, coment as a real response so I can give the credits to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause of the issue in your test is that the subject in your mocked class was set up using the rxjs `Subject` class. The usage that you have indicates that you should actually use the `BehaviorSubject` class so that any late subscribers  to the subject (subscribing after the value is pushed onto the subject) can get the most recent value when subscribing.

With the knowledge of what is happening in the mock service we can see that we have a late subscriber:

```js
generateNewToken(credential: Credential): void {
  ...
  this.subject.next(...);
  ...
}

retrieveToken(): Observable<string> {
  return this.subject.asObservable();
}
```

You can see this behavior in the usage of the mock below:

```js
this.tokenManagerService.generateNewToken(this.credential);
this.tokenManagerService.retrieveToken().subscribe(...);
```

First we are generating a new token and pushing it onto the subject, returning back to the component, and finally subscribing to the subject. By switching over to a `BehaviorSubject`, we will have no problems with having a late subscriber not seeing the value pushed from the call to generate a new token.